# Using properties in a C#.net COM component

Tags: c#, vbscript, com

I'm trying to get a C# winforms DLL to work as a COM component.

All of my methods work fine, but the properties do not - I get the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

All of the properties and methods in the interface below are marked public in the class that implements them.

```
[Guid("MY-GUID-IS-HERE")]
public interface IMyWinformsCOMComponent
{
    String clientID { get; }
    byte[] userID { get; }
    string language { get; set; }
    int productID { get; set; }
    uint version { get; }

    void thisWorksFine(string key, string value);
    uint getValue();
    void showTheForm();
}
```

Here is the vbscript sample that fails

```vb
Dim oMyWinformsCOMComponent
Set oMyWinformsCOMComponent = CreateObject("myNameSpace.MyWinformsCOMComponent")

'Works fine
Dim foo : foo = oMyWinformsCOMComponent.getValue()

'Works fine
oMyWinformsCOMComponent.thisWorksFine "myString", "myValue"

'Doesn't work
Dim lang : lang = oMyWinformsCOMComponent.language
```

Comment: Can you post the Class definition in the question as well?, prefer to check the implementation.

Comment: Related [How to make properties visible to COM in a .NET DLL (Methods DO work)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37207659/692942) - see comments.

Comment: Turns out the class constructor wasn't being called and language was calling a non static method of a member object.

Comment: which we couldn't help with just from seeing the interface.